# full-text index creation says column already indexed

Tags: hana, fulltext-index

The following SQL statement creates an error:

```
Create FullText Index "X_D_FTI"
On "XING_DESC"("DESCRIPTION")
TEXT ANALYSIS ON
CONFIGURATION 'EXTRACTION_CORE';
```

This is the error output

> Could not execute 'Create FullText Index "X_D_FTI" On "XING_DESC"("DESCRIPTION") TEXT ANALYSIS ON CONFIGURATION ...' in 5 ms 700 µs .
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [261]: invalid index name: column already indexed

Database is SAP HANA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that SAP HANA creates automatically an index for columns with data-type TEXT.

The solution was to use data type BLOB on column DESCRIPTION.